# How can I make Firefox use local Google for search?

Tags: firefox, search-engines

I live in the UK and it's really annoying that the Google results are always American. How can I configure Firefox to use google.co.uk instead of google.com?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to [this page](http://mycroft.mozdev.org/google-search-plugins.html) and find Google UK from the list. Click on that link to install google.co.uk and confirm the addition. The new engine will appear in the search bar shortly. Select it from the search bar and you're done.

You can also check this [Mozilla Help Page](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/752662) for alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the default search engine used when you type a search query in the address bar.

Enter the address "about:config",
(If it's the first time you've used this, you'll be warned that you can break things here)

Enter "keyword.url" in the "filter" box.
Double-click the result "keyword.URL", change the search provider query string and press OK, eg:
http://google.co.uk/search?q=

I've not found a way to change the firefox default home page google search, which still annoys me (I'd just change the home page, except now that is the only way to access the restore session button).

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use my local Ukrainian Google search, and I could not find the corresponding script among the Google search plugins from Mycroft. The "keyword.url" parameter was also not present in the list of my Firefox settings (Firefox v49).

I've managed to solve the problem by deleting all cookies from google.com. I found this recipe in the following article:

[How to fix Firefox search to use the local Google search](http://westhouseit.co.uk/tech-blog/how-to-fix-firefox-search-to-use-the-local-google-search/)

The author suggests removing only the cookie named PREF. I did not find it on my pc, so I deleted all cookies - and it helped.